# Передать в Class импортируемого модуля переменные

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы, импорт

Есть модуль, который я импортирую,например:

```
import module_name
```

В самом модуле класс:

```
my_class:
    some_var = my_var
    do_something()
```

есть переменная, например:

```
my_var = 777
```

Как мне из моего кода передать в класс модуля нужную мне переменную `my_var`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, my_var):
        self.some_var = my_var
        print(self.some_var)
        #do_something()


my_var = 777

myClass = MyClass(my_var)
777

print(myClass.some_var)
777
```

---

> модуль импортируется из другого файла

**main.py**

```
from module_name import MyClass

my_var = 777

myClass = MyClass(my_var)

print(myClass.some_var)
```

**module_name.py**

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, my_var):
        self.some_var = my_var
        print(self.some_var)
        #do_something()
```

Comment: у меня модуль импортируется из другого файла, ваш пример насколько я понимаю рассчитан на то, что класс не импортируется, а в этом же файле?

Comment: @babyborn добавил приме

Comment: выдает ошибку при импорте, потому что в классе переменная my_var определяется до def __init__(), как в таком случае быть?

Comment: class MyClass:
    my_var2 = my_var
    def __init__(self)

Comment: передача аргументов в класс выполняется через метод `def __init__(self, my_var):` . Что такое `my_var2` ? и почему вы написали `my_var2 = my_var` перед методом ``def __init__(self, my_var):`` ?

Comment: в модуле в def __init__ переменная не передается вообще, передается в некоторые другие функции, а определяется сразу в начале класса. my_var2 просто привел для примера чтобы было видно определение переменной в начале класса

Comment: @babyborn замените `def __init__(self):` на `def __init__(self, my_var):` . Переместите `my_var2 = my_var`  после `def __init__(self, my_var):`

Comment: @s-nick а у других функций будет доступ к my_var? без объявления ее глобальной

Comment: @babyborn для того чтобы иметь доступ к переменной в любом методе класса вы должны: 1. принять ее в методе `__init__` и сделать ее атрибутом метода `__init__`  вот так `self.my_var2 = my_var`. После чего вы в любом методе класса оперируете с `self.my_var2`